# How do I get the root directory of a relative path

Tags: go, path

I need to extract the name first of the first directory in a relative path.

I know I can go about:

```
relPath := "a/b/c/file.so"
splitPath := strings.Split(relPath, string(os.PathSeparator))
rootDirName := splitPath[0]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What do you mean by "better way". This is probably the easiest and shortest way to do it. There is only missing a check of  `splitPath` length.

Comment: @dom Just making sure. Languages sometimes have non-obvious but very helpful features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking whether there is way to do it with 1 standard Go function: not that I know of.

An alternative way would be:

```
relPath := "a/b/c/file.so"
i := strings.Index(relPath, string(os.PathSeparator))
rootDirName := relPath[:i]
```

Or if it is possible that the path contains no `/` at all:

```
relPath := "a/b/c/file.so"
i := strings.Index(relPath, string(os.PathSeparator))
rootDirName := ""
if i != -1 {
    rootDirName = relPath[:i]
}
```

This has the benefit of not having to split the whole string and might, therefore, be a little faster on long paths.

Comment: Make sure you check the index, else if no path separator is found in `relPath`, you get a runtime panic.

Comment: Also, calling `path.Clean` or `filepath.Clean` first might be a good idea, depending on what kind of paths you're dealing with, and what you want to happen if the path is something like `./a/../b/c`.